# Qt Designer menu disappears when title set to English

Tags: c++, qt-designer

I'm facing a problem I don't understand. I.e. if I want my menu bar to have two menus. 
If I set the title of one to "Edit" it is not shown when running the application. If I set it to "Bearbeiten" (that's Edit in German) it is shown. I prefer English titles. But even some German titles are not shown.

I think source code is not necessary. But if so, let me know.

I'm on OS X Yosemite/ Qt Creator 3.4.1 (opensource) based on Qt 5.4.2 (Clang 6.0, 64bit)

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards

Edit: On Windows the same project shows all English Menus as desired

Comment: There is a feature called "menu bar merging" for [QMenuBar on OS X](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qmenubar.html#qmenubar-on-os-x), however it should not affect entries called "edit" (according to the documentation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read this yesterday but seriously, I did not get a clue out of this.

Comment: If I set the title in code using the tr()-function it works. But this is annoying

Comment: you might file a bug report at https://bugreports.qt.io/ with a simple reproducible example which demonstrates behavior different than what is documented